# ¿Cómo se puede eliminar un vector a través de un puntero?

Tags: c++

Quiero eliminar el indice 0 del vector `image` a través del puntero que apunta al `image[0]`. Lo que hice hasta ahora:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> image;

void main(){
 image.push_back(5);
 image.push_back(10);

 int *p=&image[0];

 cout << *p << endl;
 delete *p; // QUIERO ELIMINAR image[0] algo como image.delete(0);
}
```

Comment: main() devuelve int

Answer (score 4):

Tienes unos errores conceptuales que te llevan a intentar usar la memoria dinámica (heap) de manera extraña.

#### ¿Quién se responsabiliza de la memoria dinámica?

La memoria dinámica se solicita mediante el operador `new` y se borra usando el operador `delete`. La responsabilidad de aplicar `delete` sobre la memoria solicitada dinámicamente pertenece código que ha realizado el `new`.

En tu caso no hay ningún `new` en tu código así que estás intentando liberar memoria de la que no eres responsable. Para borrar la memoria que `std::vector` ha solicitado debes confiar en la interfaz que el objeto `std::vector` proporciona.

#### `delete` no traga con todo.

El operador `delete` se usa sobre punteros, pero no todos los punteros son borrables mediante `delete`, por ejemplo:

```
int entero = 0;
int arreglo[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int *arreglo_heap = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};

delete &entero;
delete &arreglo[3];
delete &arreglo_heap[3];
```

Todas las llamadas al operador `delete` del código anterior causan un error **en tiempo de ejecución**. No fallan en tiempo de compilación porque [sintácticamente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintaxis) son instrucciones correctas (el operador `delete` se usa sobre punteros), pero su semántica es incorrecta:

- `delete &entero` intenta aplicar el operador `delete` sobre memoria solicitada en la pila en lugar del heap.
- `delete &arreglo[3]` intenta aplicar el operador `delete` sobre memoria solicitada en la pila en lugar del heap, además intenta liberar parcialmente una zona de memoria que pertenece a un conjunto más grande sin liberar el resto del conjunto.
- `delete &arreglo_heap[3]` intenta liberar parcialmente una zona de memoria que pertenece a un conjunto más grande sin liberar el resto del conjunto.

En C++ no es posible pedir un bloque de memoria y después borrarlo parcialmente, así que si quisieramos achatar `arreglo_heap` deberíamos borrarlo al completo y pedir menos memoria:

```
int *arreglo_heap = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};

// Oh vaya, creo que 5 enteros son demasiados, mejor uso 4...

// Borro TODO el arreglo...
delete[] arreglo_heap;
// ... pido menos menoria:
int *arreglo_heap = new int[4]{1,2,3,5};
```

En este caso en lugar de usar el operador `delete` usamos el operador `delete[]`, que es el operador que **debe** usarse para borrar arreglos alojados en el heap, no es posible borrar una posición intermedia del arreglo.

#### ¿Qué hace `std::vector` con su memoria?

Internamente `std::vector` solicita memoria dinámica para alojar los datos que se le añadan mediante [`insert`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) o [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back); el objeto guarda un búfer interno que redimensiona según sea necesario.

Normalmente `std::vector` reserva una cantidad de memoria mayor que la que necesita y usa esa cantidad reservada para guardar datos hasta que se queda sin espacio; en ese momento crea un **nuevo** búfer con más espacio y mueve/copia los datos al nuevo búfer. Esto lo hace porque solicitar memoria dinámica es un proceso costoso y este contenedor garantiza que todos los datos serán anexos (cada elemento está junto al resto de elementos en memoria, en lugar de disperso). Puedes consultar la cantidad de memoria reservada y usada por un `std::vector` llamando las funciones [`capacity`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) y [`size`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) respectivamente.

#### ¿Qué has intentado hacer tú?

Has accedido a un elemento individual del `std::vector` a través del operador corchetes ([`operator []`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)) el cuál devuelve una referencia al elemento solicitado; este elemento es uno de los que pertenecen al búfer interno de `std::vector`.

Obtienes la dirección de memoria de dicho elemento con el operador et (`&`) y se lo pasas a `delete` como memoria a liberar. Como ya hemos visto que **`delete` no traga con todo** y ahora que sabemos **qué hace `std::vector` con su memoria** sabemos que liberar mediante `delete` un espacio intermedio de un arreglo dinámico provoca fallos en tiempo de ejecución.

#### ¿Cómo se puede eliminar un vector a través de un puntero?

No se puede. Pero las respuestas de [ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24180/2742) y [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24289/2742) te dan una idea alternativa para conseguir el mismo efecto. Por mi parte presentaré una solución basada en la propuesta de ArtEze usando [`rotate`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) y [`resize`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
// Rotamos a la izquierda, el primer elemento pasa a ser el ultimo
std::rotate(image.begin(), image.begin() + 1, image.end());
// Borramos el ultimo elemento
image.resize(image.size() - 1);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6KMzRIEeodZ3HdF1).

---

PD: `main` debe devolver `int` no `void`.

Comment: Gracias la verdad que c++ nunca fue mi fuerte, pero cada vez me veo forzado a usarlo mas, debido a que hago extensiones en c++ para php y bueno si esta claro que no soy ningun iluminado. Muy buena explicacion gracias...

Comment: Por lo que veo no hace falta no resize ni rotate mira: [ACA](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xItLA0iWtkZlIv4Z)

Comment: @GermanBernhardt efectivamente, porque esa es la solución de [eferion](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24289/2742); la de `rotate` y `resize` está basada en la solución de [ArtEze](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24180/2742) que desplaza los elementos a la izquierda para eliminar el primero.

Answer (score 2):

No es posible eliminar el primer elemento de un **vector**. Lo que se debe hacer es asignarle el siguiente, y avanzar, y así hasta terminar de recorrer el *vector*, voy a suponer que el último valor es un cero.

Esta función recibe el nombre de `shift` (corrimiento). También se puede hacer una analogía con las operaciones `bitwise`, es decir, algo parecido a multiplicar o dividir por 2, si esto fuera una lista de decimales, sería por 10.

```
/*
    Al primero le asigno el valor del segundo
    al segundo el del tercero,
    al tercero el del cuarto, y así.    
*/
for(int i=0;image[i+1]!=0;i++){ image[i] = image[i+1]; }
```

Comment: El problema de tu solución es que las dos últimas posiciones tendrán el mismo valor.

Comment: @eferion además de que si los elementos del vector fuesen costosos de copiar, ese bucle sería un cuello de botella.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, no pensé en el costo, ahora pensé crear un puntero hacia el siguiente valor y hacer de cuenta que es el _array_, pero funciona para borrar elementos, no para añadir. Tu respuesta es buena. Sería bueno que investiguen de hacer un árbol binario para acceder a las posiciones (consume más memoria).

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de un contenedor de la STL (salvo std::array) puedes eliminar un elemento usando iteradores:

```
void main(){
  vector<int> image;
  image.push_back(5);
  image.push_back(10);

  // opcion genérica: avanzas a la posición que quieres eliminar
  vector<int>::iterator it = std::next(image.begin(),0);

  // opción específica: image.begin() devuelve el iterador a la primera posición
  vector<int>::iterator it = image.begin();

  std::cout << *it;
  image.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Así tal cual no me funciona, falta un punto y coma en la segunda línea y me aparece que se está redeclarando `it`, también hice un cout abajo de todo para ver si cambió... El resultado es que funciona bien el `erase`, yo no conocía esa técnica.

Comment: Lee los comentarios del código... it está efectivamente declarada dos veces porque hay dos opciones... comenta una de las dos. En cuanto al punto y coma error mío al copiar el código, lo corrijo en un momento. Gracias por la apreciación

Comment: Pues, funciona bien de las dos maneras.

Comment: jejeje. esa es la idea. La solución genérica sirve para borrar un elemento sabiendo su posición (siendo esta variable), la específica te servirá únicamente parar borrar el primer elemento

Comment: Si entendi algo me ayudaron un monton muchachos gracias.a erase ya lo habia decubierto hurgando

Comment: @ArtEze @eferion @PaperBirdMaster Tambien note que `vector<int>::iterator it = std::next(image.begin(),1);` es igual a hacer `vector<int>::iterator it = image.begin()+1;`

Comment: Si me di cuenta que lo que queria hacer no se puede porque si tengo *p0 que apunta a image[0], *p1 -> image[1] y *p2 -> image[2] y borro image[1], image[2] pasa a ocupar la direccion de memoria de image[1] y eso no me sirve para lo que intentaba hacer. estaba manejando resources en php extension y al tipo de variables resources php lo maneja a travez de un puntero.

Comment: @GermanBernhardt esa aritmética de iteradores funciona porque los iteradores de `std::vector` son [RandomAccessIterator](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).